# activeadmin polymorphic type compare

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I have a polymorphic association:

```
class Option < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :structurable, polymorphic: true
end
```

Can be connected to People or Animals entities.

I want to check if an Option has a Person or an Animal connected to it? How should I check?

```
o = Option.first
o.structurable == :animal
```

or

```
o.structurable_type == :animal
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess this would help

```
o.structurable.class == Animal
```

OR

```
o.structurable_type == 'Animal'
```

Answer (score 1):

Also You can try this for checking the Animal object.

```
o.structurable.kind_of?(Animal)
```